# Sort a vector of characters according to successive criteria

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings with different elements inside:

```
vec = c("aaa.bbb0bbb0.fff110321.csv", "aaa.bbb0bbb015.fff120321.csv", 
        "aaa.bbb02bbb015.fff150321.csv","aaa.bbb02bbb015.fff130321.csv")
```

I want to sort these elements according to the numbers after the first `bbb` being increasing and then the number after the second `bbb` being increasing and finally after the date at the end of the string.

A solution to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base R option -

For ease of understanding I have extracted the relevant values in separate columns using regex and then ordered the data based on our preference.

```
res <- cbind(vec, strcapture("b+(\\d+)b+(\\d+).*?(\\d+)", vec, 
    proto = list(first = integer(), second = integer(), date = character()))) |>
  transform(date = as.Date(date, '%d%m%y')) 

res <- res[with(res, order(first, second, date)), ]
res

#                            vec first second       date
#1    aaa.bbb0bbb0.fff110321.csv     0      0 2021-03-11
#2  aaa.bbb0bbb015.fff120321.csv     0     15 2021-03-12
#4 aaa.bbb02bbb015.fff130321.csv     2     15 2021-03-13
#3 aaa.bbb02bbb015.fff150321.csv     2     15 2021-03-15
```

---

`tidyverse` method -

```
library(tidyverse)

res <- tibble(vec) %>%
  extract(vec, c("first", "second", "date"), "b+(\\d+)b+(\\d+).*?(\\d+)", 
          remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>%
  arrange(first, second, date)
```

If you are interested in output vector you can get that from `res$vec`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my expression, the date are the last numbers but there are other numbers before. So based on your answer, I made the following changes `cbind(fich_simu, strcapture("sig+(\\d+)sig+(\\d+).*(\\d+{6})", vec, 
    proto = list(first = integer(), second = integer(), date = character()))) |>
  transform(date = as.Date(date, '%d%m%y')) `